# How to add months to timestamp

Tags: php

I have a timestamp $timestamp. How do I add 6 months to that timestamp using strtotime?

I was thinking of doing

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
$sixmonths_fromnow = strtotime('+6 months', $date);
```

but can I use strtotime directly on the timestamp? do I have to use the date() function first?

Comment: A quick check in the manual would give you the answer.

Comment: `strtotime('+6 months', $timestamp)` is all you'd need. there is **ZERO** point in converting your timestamp into a string, which forces strtotime to convert it back to a timestamp anyways. major waste of cpu cycles.

Comment: Also, while someone no doubt answers this, keep in the back of your head that you're not adding half a year, you're adding half a year's worth of seconds to that timestamp. Things that might actually matter when dealing with time line timezone specific time corrections will not be taken into account and the time of day before you add half a year may not actually be the time of day "half a year later", so if you're doing this for more than just casual "looks half a year laterish", use a locale-enabled datetime library instead.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the `timestamp`:

```
$sixmonths_fromnow = strtotime('+6 months', $timestamp);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $sixmonths_fromnow);
```